# Can implementation specific lengths be found at compile time in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Is there anyway I can find out the length of certain properties in OpenGL at compile time? Specifically, the result of querying `GL_MAX_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFERS` or the maximum number of texture bindings? Is it unreasonable to expect these to be obtainable at compile time?

Comment: Imagine you compile your app at your PC. Turn it off. Replace graphic card with more buffers, more lights, etc. Turn it on and run your app.

Comment: @Laethnes Yeah, that doesn't make much sense, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no implementation at compile-time.

That said, the GL spec. guarantees certain minimums. You can find them in ***[`Section 23.53 - Implementation Dependent Values`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf)***.

*Hopefully your PDF reader can rotate documents or your monitor can rotate, because those tables are pretty hard to read the way they are. There is too much information to orient them horizontally on each page.*

Comment: Gah, I knew I wasn't the only one rotating my screen for them!